# zsh command line processing - separating the last arguments from the previous ones

Tags: zsh

I am writing a zsh script, which is invoked with a variable number of arguments, such as

```
 scriptname a b c d filename
```

Inside the script, I want first to loop over the arguments (except the last one) and process them, and finally do something with the processed data and the last argument (filename).

I got this working, but am not entirely happy with my solution. Here is what I came up with (where `process` and `apply` are some other scripts not relevant to my problem):

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -u
x=""
filename=$@[-1]
# Process initial arguments
for ((i=1; i<$#; i++))
do
  x+=$(process ${@[$i]}) 
done
apply $x $filename
```

I find the counting loop too cumbersome. If `filename` where the first argument, I would do a `shift` and then could simply loop over the arguments, after having saved the filename. However I want to keep the filename as the last argument (for consistency with other tools).

Any ideas how to write this neatly without counting loop?

Comment: Moving the filename to the first position wouldn't necessarily be *inconsistent* with other tools. Some versions of `mv`, for example, allow something like `mv -t dest src1 src2 src3` as replacement for `mv src1 src2 src3 dest`.

Comment: @chepner : I'm aware of this; I should have be more precise: This is a script which is part of our toolset, and the other tools in it have already this layout for the interface, so I wanted to stick with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice off the last argument from the original list and save them into an array, if thats an option

```sh
args=("${@:1:$# -1}")
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do          # iterate over all, except the last
  printf '%s\n' "$arg"
done
```

Using the array as a placeholder is optional as you can iterate over the arguments slice directly i.e. `for arg in "${@:1:$# -1}"; do`. The syntax is even available in `bash` also.

---

As pointed out by [chepner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754456/zsh-command-line-processing-separating-the-last-arguments-from-the-previous-on/68754546?noredirect=1#comment121526307_68754546), you could use a `zsh` specifc syntax as

```
for arg in $@[1,-2]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$arg"
done
```

Comment: `zsh` has a simpler slicing syntax available: `$@[1,-2]`